# What is the correct adjective order for "unique" and "only"?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

Which category of adjectives would "unique" and "only" (as in "only child") fall under? I'm asking with regards to where it would fit in terms of [the adjective order on this graph](https://www.hip-books.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Adjectives-order-in-English-grammar.png).

For example, would I say "The unique small house" or "The small unique house" or even "The small, unique house"?

Comment: _Only_ is a quantifier; it has own syntax. _Unique_ is a descriptive adjective made from a quantifier. Which scale of adjective order would you like to place it on?

Comment: Oh I was looking at the adjective order on this graph: https://www.hip-books.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Adjectives-order-in-English-grammar.png For example would I say "The unique small house" or "The small unique house" or even "The small, unique house"? @JohnLawler

Comment: As _unique_ means _the only one of its kind_, I think it would always come before any other adjectives. "This unique little house is..."

Comment: There are several variants of the 'Royal Order of Adjectives', and linguists who think they're all too broad-brush to be ultimately useful. If you're after peripheral cases, try 'mere' and the adjective-or-is-it 'galore'.

Comment: @KateBunting - This is the only unique little house in the neighborhood.

Comment: This may be a stylistic point, but it seems the neither word sits comfortably with other other descriptive adjectives.  I agree with Kate Bunting that when it does occur in the kind of context she gives.  'Only' applies across the noun and its other descriptors:  "Sea View is the only large, airy, well-maintained period house with its own beach hut that I can afford."  I make no claims for the order of the descriptors, except to note that the prepositional phrase descriptor must follow the noun.  I have no idea why I used the particular order of attributes before the noun:  it 'felt' right.

Comment: Since the adjective "only" modifies NPs (noun phrases), it follows that it occurs at the beginning of the NP, before other modifiers.

Comment: "He's a unique only child" uses 'only child' as a compound, which of course can't be separated. "It's the only unique diecast model car I own" is possible.

Comment: It could be argued that 'unique' is a determiner like 'two' or 'only' and therefore comes before the adjectives. If it's not a determiner then it's an opinion adjective so it comes in the first category after the determiners anyway. Saying "only unique ..." is right whichever you choose but it does lay you open to charges of tautology.

Comment: "Two is a determinative, but "only" isn't. "Only" either a focusing adverb, as in "Ed loves [only his work]", or an adjective, as in "My only reservation is ..."